# Google location history kml file

Tags: kml

What does `0</gx:coord>` mean?

Example:

```
<when>2017-04-02T04:00:09Z</when>
<gx:coord>-177.1773543 33.7720963 0</gx:coord>
```

Does that mean the location was manually entered?

Comment: that didn't come out right 0</gx:coord>

Comment: 0</gx:coord> what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

**What are GPS coordinates?**

GPS coordinates are formed by two components that are its latitude  and longitude. The north-south position of a point is given by its latitude when its longitude gives information about its east-west position.

However, *there is a third element required to locate a point*, its **altitude**. In the most typical use cases, GPS coordinates are needed for locations on the surface of the Earth, making this third parameter less important. However, it is as necessary as the latitude and longitude to define a complete and accurate GPS location.

*IIRC, it is measured in meters from sea level.*

As far as what `0</gx:coord>` means specifically, it is stating 0 meters above sea level (or at sea level), and `</gx:coord>` is the end of the coordinates statement starting with `<gx:coord>`